# Does gevent monkey patched Queue.put yield (context switch)?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, gevent, monkeypatching

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
from queue import Queue
import random
import time


def getter(q):
    while True:
        print('getting')
        v = q.get()
        print(f'got {v}')

def putter(q):
    while True:
        print(f'start putting')
        v = int(random.random() * 1000)
        # `put_nowait` also seems to yield
        # q.put(v)
        q.put_nowait(v)
        print(f'done putting with {v}')

        if random.random() < 0.5:
            print(f'yield')
            time.sleep(0)


queue = Queue()


gevent.spawn(getter, queue)
gevent.spawn(putter, queue)

time.sleep(1000)
```

Doesn't matter if I use `queue.put` or `queue.put_nowait`, I saw logs like

```
# start putting
# got 25
# getting
# done putting with 535
```

Does that suggest gevent might do context switch each time it executes `queue.put`?

#### Update

I modified the code a bit

```
flag = True

def getter(q):
    while True:
        print('getting')
        global flag
        flag = False
        v = q.get()
        print(f'got {v}')

def putter(q):
    v = 0
    while True:
        print(f'start putting {v}')
        global flag
        flag = True
        # `put_nowait` also seems to yield
        # q.put(v)
        q.put_nowait(v)
        if not flag:
            raise Exception('yield happened')

        print(f'done putting with {v}')
        v += 1

        time.sleep(0)
        # If I sleep with non-zero, the above seems to only yield once at the beginning.
        # time.sleep(0.000001)


queue = Queue()


def myTracer(event, args):
    src, target = args
    if event == "switch":
        # print("from %s switch to %s" % (src, target))
        # Print to stdout like the rest of the code. Otherwise the order of stdout & stderr is not guaranteed.
        traceback.print_stack(file=sys.stdout)
    elif event == "throw":
        print("from %s throw exception to %s" % (src, target))


# greenlet.settrace(myTracer)

gevent.spawn(getter, queue)
putter(queue)
```

With patched Python Queue,

- If I `sleep(0)`, it might do context switch.
- If I `sleep(0.0000001)`, it only yield once at the beginning.
- If I don't sleep at all, it only yield once at the beginning, and the getter doesn't have a chance to run afterwards.

Looking at the stack trace, I found `Queue.put` calls `notify`, which calls `lock.acquire(0)`. It was then patched so that it calls `sleep()` in `gevent/thread.py`

If I use `gevent.queue.Queue` instead of Python `Queue`, it doesn't seem to do context switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [greenlet.settrace](https://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/greenlet.html?highlight=settrace#tracing-support) with a callback function to detect context switches.
Adding that to your code shows that both `put` and `put_nowait` do context switches.

```
...

def myTracer(event, args):
    src, target = args
    if event == "switch":
        print("from %s switch to %s" % (src, target))
    elif event == "throw":
        print("from %s throw exception to %s" % (src, target))


greenlet.settrace(myTracer)


queue = Queue()
gevent.spawn(getter, queue)
gevent.spawn(putter, queue)

time.sleep(5)
```

You gonna see a lot of 'switching' debug messages in stdout:

```
...
done putting with 106
start putting
from <Greenlet at 0x10418e150: putter(<queue.Queue object at 0x1034d9460>)> switch to <Hub '' at 0x10416a400 select default pending=0 ref=3 thread_ident=0x106d15dc0>
from <Hub '' at 0x10416a400 select default pending=0 ref=1 thread_ident=0x106d15dc0> switch to <Greenlet at 0x10418e150: putter(<queue.Queue object at 0x1034d9460>)>
done putting with 487
start putting
....
```

**Edit/Note:**

I am using Python3.8 and gevent==20.9.0. When testing I removed the whole if-condition `if random.random() ...`, but piping stdout to a file and searching for `getter` context switches and `getting` both are present in stdout.

I didn't investigate further, but if you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/61432c16a6a8903f94731d9cb707f0b93ff7492f/src/gevent/queue.py#L268) you can see there is an explicit call `getter.switch(getter)` probably that's what's causing the context switches.

Comment: If I remove `print(f'yield')  time.sleep(0)` from my code, `getter` seems never to be triggered, although the `settrace` shows there are context switchs. Do you know why?